# How do browsers decide what data to use for auto-fill on each input?

Tags: html, autofill

I've seen other questions asking how auto-fill works, but the answers all explain how to make it work, which is not what I want.  I want to stop it from working. And I also realize that there are many questions out there asking that specific thing, but the answer is always to set autocomplete=off, which we all know is useless because browsers don't honour it.

And besides that, my question is a little bit different because what I'm really asking is how the browser decides which inputs to populate with what data, because I'm hoping with that knowledge I can prevent the problem I'm having.

Specifically the issue I'm having is that every time I open up my "change password" page, my search input is automatically being filled with the username.  I'm trying to understand why it's doing that so that I can prevent it.

My input does not have a name or a label or an autocomplete attribute. It's just very simply as shown here.  So in what universe does it make sense for a browser to find a field with the id "searchinput" and think that it makes sense to auto-fill it with a username?

```
<input type=text id=searchinput placeholder='Search'>
```

Also, on the change password page, the first of the two password fields is automatically filled in (presumably with the matching password but I can't see it because it's all circles).  So why are these browsers auto-filling my search input with the username and how can I prevent it?

To explain a bit further what my code is doing:  When the user selects "change password" from the menu, I load my change password page into a div (using jquery load) on the existing page and slide it down to cover most of the browser window (minus the header and menu), which means whatever page they're currently on is still there underneath, and that's also why my search input is still visible.  The auto-fill happens as soon as I load my change password page.

Comment: I don't think there's a specification, every browser has its own heuristics, and the programmers frequently update them in new versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, the reason the input field was being auto-populated with the username is because Chrome auto-fills the first password field it finds (and you can't stop it), and then also auto-fills with the user name whatever input field comes before the password field in the DOM, regardless of what the name, id, or purpose of that field might be.  In my case, it was the search input.

So to get around this I had to create another input just before the new password input and hide it out of view with absolute positioning so that Chrome will fill this useless field instead of my search input.  Sigh.

```
<input type=text style='width:0px;position:absolute;right:-100px'>
```

I also added an "out of view" password field so that Chrome will auto-fill this field instead and not the first password field in my form.

```
<input type=password style='width:0px;position:absolute;right:-100px'>
```